# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Produkt LIKE '%{0}%' Or Model LIKE '%{0}%' Or Firma LIKE '%{0}%'  ", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
        foreach (string s in dv)
        {
            list.Add(s);
        }
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            list.Clear();
        }
    }
```

There is no any error in program, so i can run it. But when i put some text into textbox, i'am receiving error like this: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.String'".

Could You tell me, what I am doing wrong ?.

Comment: *Always* state exactly in *what line* the error occurs when asking a question, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to convert `DataRowView` to string here which is not possible and I assume that is not what you wanted.

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
{
    list.Add(row["Model"].ToString()); //this will add models from selected rows to list
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do `string s in dv` since dv contains a collection of `DataRowViews` which are not strings. You need to get the string from the column/columns in the `DataRowView` instead.